# Loading in iframe on ajax form submit

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I've a form with couple of buttons, on submit it redirect to third party site for authentication.
On the submit I want to load that inside iframe on same page. How I can do that?

Comment: How do you set the redirect now?

Comment: I'n using OpenId Connect module, redirection is set here 
https://cgit.drupalcode.org/openid_connect/tree/src/Form/OpenIDConnectLoginForm.php?h=8.x-1.x#n118

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do it with jQuery.

1. Add this code in your template: `<iframe id="frame-id" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>`
2. Add this jQuery:

   ```
   $("#SUBMIT-ID").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();//This prevents the site from being redirected.
     var a_href = $('.A-THAT-HAS-REDIRECT-CLASS').attr('href');
     $("#frame-id").attr("src", a_href);
   });
   ```